# Expression: Sequence not ordered

Tags: c++, crash, std, intersection

I'm trying to find the intersect between 2 strings. I'm using the following code:

```
std::string a = "asd", b = "afd";

std::string intersect;
std::set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(intersect));
```

It compiles successfully, but after running the program instant crashes with the following error:

[image]

Any suggestion what is causing this problem?

Comment: The error message tells you -- the inputs to set_intersection need to be sorted.

Answer (score 6):

You should sort `a` and `b` first before passing them to [**`std::set_intersection()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection):

> `template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt >
>   OutputIt set_intersection( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
>                              InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
>                              OutputIt d_first );
>   (1) 
>   template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2,
>             class OutputIt, class Compare >
>   OutputIt set_intersection( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
>                              InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
>                              OutputIt d_first, Compare comp );
>   (2)`
>
> Constructs a sorted range beginning at `d_first` consisting of elements that are found in both sorted ranges `[first1, last1)` and `[first2, last2)`. **The first version expects both input ranges to be sorted with `operator<`, the second version expects them to be sorted with the given comparison function `comp`**.

So, add

```
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
```